# what is the php variable names of the product attributes on the product page?

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I wonder what the name is of the different product attributes that are loaded on the product page. Is there somewhere where they are listed? And what about the custom ones. How can I figure out their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all custom product attributes name which is listed on product detail.

Run below **sql** query to **phpmyadmin** and you will get all list

```
SELECT `attribute_code` FROM `eav_attribute` INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` where eav_attribute.attribute_id = catalog_eav_attribute.attribute_id AND eav_attribute.entity_type_id = 4 and eav_attribute.is_user_defined = 1
```